# Getting correct time when user change device time manually?

Tags: swift, firebase, timezone

I am using Firebase as backend for my iOS application. and when user change his device time manually in settings he can make action in future times.

so I searched internet, and I did not see any native solution in Swift to detect real time.

and I am wondering is the problem can be solve by Swift code or using Firebase SDK sever time ?

[Edit]
how we can show correct time in UI not device time ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ServerValue.timestamp()` in firebase.

For an example :

```
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("userExample")
    let values = ["firstName": "Joe", "lastName": "Bloggs", "timestamp": ServerValue.timestamp()] as [String : Any]

    ref.updateChildValues(values) { (err, ref) in

        if let err = err {
            print("failed to upload user data", err)
            return
        }

    }
```

More more information check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps).